# Reading an HTML File from Folder in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I want to read an HTML file in Python 3.4.3.

I have tried:

```
import urllib.request
fname = r"C:\Python34\html.htm"
HtmlFile = open(fname,'w')
print (HtmlFile)
```

This prints:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Python34\\html.htm' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
```

I want to get the HTML source so that I can parse it with beautiful soup.

Comment: If you want to read you shouldn't open it for writing ;) `open(fname, 'w')` => `open(fname, 'r')`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to read the contents of the file.

```
HtmlFile = open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
source_code = HtmlFile.read()
```

Comment: im getting this error for the above lineFile "C:/Python34/pretty.py", line 4, in <module>
    source_code = HtmlFile.read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4411: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Use encoding to read the file - `HtmlFile = open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Remember to close the file when you're done: `HtmlFile.close()`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to read the saved HTML file in the folder. I tried code mentioned by Vikasa but was getting an error. So I changed the code and tried to read it again it worked for me. The code is as follows:

```
    fname = 'page_source.html' #this html file is stored on the same folder of the code file
    html_file = open(fname, 'r')
    source_code = html_file.read()
```

print the html page using

```
source_code
```

It will print the content read from the page_source.html file.